# Instagram's video cache dir inaccessible in the latest update

Tags: android, instagram

A few months ago I created an app which let the user see and manage Instagram's offline video caches like a gallery. formerly the dir was located in here :

internal-memory/Android/data/com.instagram.android/cache/video

but since the last Instagram update that dir seems to have only one file : journal
I searched around and found nothing. even rooted my phone and used any root explorer I knew to search deeper. the only time I could see the cache was when I connected my phone to my PC and there they were, right where they used to be before, but not accessible through windows either. I couldn't copy the files. apparently the files weren't exactly there !

So, I have two questions now:

1- How can I access Instagram's cached files?

2- I'm really interested to know what they did to hide these files? it would be useful in many ways to be able to hide files in public internal memory in a way that no file manager could explore.

======

## Edit :

they're not hiding anything, just using exoplayer to cache and stream video files. right now I'm trying to merge them back together. I'd appreciate any help because I can't figure it out by my self.

Comment: well, apparently the files are not in the old dir at all. windows must have shown me a cached version of that dir all along because now it's not there. any ideas ?

Comment: it seems that it uses Exo cached files and they don't seem to be encrypted since I can open the first part of each stream in any player. but I tried some ways to merge them and failed. does anyone know how to convert these files back to it's initial state (which is .mp4) ?